# Mouse Cursor Scaleform 4 / AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, udk, interface

I just solved my issue

in my object (on the stage) I forgot to name the element

---

I'm trying to make workin a custom mouse cursor on my Scaleform menu.
I have follow some tutorials but nothing good...

Right now I have tried the Matt Doyle's AS :

```
import scaleform.gfx.Extensions;
Extensions.enabled = true;

Mouse.hide();
var mCursor:MovieClip;
mCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
mCursor.tabEnabled = false;

function handleMouseMove( e:MouseEvent ):void 
{
    mCursor.x = e.stageX;
    mCursor.y = e.stageY;
}

stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove, false, 0, true );
```

but i'm little confused on how declare the cursor
should I add it on the stage, or can I use some `addChild()` to have it on the screen

for information `mCursor` is also the name of the cursor movieClip in my library

Comment: Instead of updating your question with the solution, you should post an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just solved my issue

in my object (on the stage) I forgot to name the element